# How to solve view limit minimum is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value error?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

This is my data:

```
             Last
Date                  
2019-02-19  277.850006
2019-02-20  278.410004
2019-02-21  277.420013
2019-02-22  279.140015
2019-02-25  279.940002
```

I am using this function for daily data and it works great.

```
def corr_window (data, cdw, dyf, corr_level):

    '''
    data = historical data
    cdw = corralation days window
    dyf = number of days forward
    corr_level = desirable correlation level
    '''
    mylabels = ['Dax', str(dyf)+' days forward']
    s=[]
    data2= data[-cdw:]
    data[-cdw:].plot(title='Dax last {} trading Days'.format(str(cdw)))
    for i in range(len(data)-cdw*2):
        if (pearsonr(data[i:i+cdw],data2)[0]) > corr_level:
            s.append((data.iloc[i+cdw+dyf]['Last']/data.iloc[i+cdw]['Last'])-1)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
            data[i:i+cdw+dyf].plot(title="Correlation:"+str(pearsonr(data[i:i+cdw],data2)[0]),ax=ax)
            data[i+cdw:i+cdw+dyf].plot(color = 'red',label='Days forward', ax=ax)
            ax.legend(labels=mylabels, loc=0)
            plt.tight_layout();
    return print(f'Average Return after {dyf} days is {round(np.mean(s)*100,2)}% \nfor {len(s)} occurrences\
    ----> {np.round(sum(1 for x in s if x>0)/len(s)*100,1)}% positive returns\n')
```

when trying to move the data to resolution, I use:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.Date + ' ' + data.Time)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format=' %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
```

and my data looks like this:

```
                    Date        Time        Last
2019-03-01 20:51:00 2019-03-01  20:51:00.0  11628.5
2019-03-01 20:54:00 2019-03-01  20:54:00.0  11627.5
2019-03-01 20:57:00 2019-03-01  20:57:00.0  11633.5
2019-03-01 21:00:00 2019-03-01  21:00:00.0  11633.0
2019-03-01 21:03:00 2019-03-01  21:03:00.0  11629.5
```

When running the above function on my minutes data I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -24654.425000000003 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units.
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace of your error log?
Which line of the code generates the error? Is it `plt.tight_layout()`?

Comment: 1) you should convert time as `timedelta`: `pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])`. 2) do index afterward: `df.index = df['Date'] + df['Time']`.

Comment: Is `data[i+cdw:i+cdw+dyf]` valid? Or should it be `data.iloc[i+cdw:i+cdw+dyf]`?

Comment: in fact I'll bet your error happens even earlier, here `data2= data[-cdw:]`. You are passing a negative number as an index but you `data` dataframe has a datetime index. If you wanted to index the last `cdw` rows in pandas you need to use `iloc` unless your index containes sequential integers, which yours does not as it contains dates. So you'd need `data2= data.iloc[-cdw:, :]` and then use it again on the next line instead of recomputing it.

Comment: Please check first: `data.index.min()` to be sure there is no error in your input dataframe. If it happens to be `-24654.425000000003`? Or maybe log your `data`before `plot` function?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `return print(...)` doesn't really make any sense. That prints to output, then returns `None`. Also I suspect you could make pinpointing the issue easier for yourself and/or others here by trimming this down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look but it seems to work fine for me with this:
(the only adjustment is the addition of `.values.ravel()` since it seems that `scipy.pearsonr` doesn't like dataframes...)

can you provide a (not)working example?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame([['2019-03-01 20:51:00', '11628.5'],
                     ['2019-03-01 20:54:00', '11627.5'],
                     ['2019-03-01 20:57:00', '11633.5'],
                     ['2019-03-01 21:00:00', '11633.0'],
                     ['2019-03-01 21:03:00', '11629.5']], 
                    columns=['index', 'Last'])

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.pop('index'))
data['Last'] = data['Last'].astype(float)

# make the dataframe a bit longer...
data = data.append(data)


# --------------------------

def corr_window (data, cdw, dyf, corr_level):

    '''
    data = historical data
    cdw = corralation days window
    dyf = number of days forward
    corr_level = desirable correlation level
    '''
    mylabels = ['Dax', str(dyf)+' days forward']
    s=[]
    data2= data[-cdw:]
    data[-cdw:].plot(title='Dax last {} trading Days'.format(str(cdw)))
    for i in range(len(data)-cdw*2):
        if (pearsonr(data[i:i+cdw].values.ravel(),data2.values.ravel())[0]) > corr_level:
            s.append((data.iloc[i+cdw+dyf]['Last']/data.iloc[i+cdw]['Last'])-1)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
            data[i:i+cdw+dyf].plot(title="Correlation:"+str(pearsonr(data[i:i+cdw].values.ravel(),data2.values.ravel())[0]),ax=ax)
            data[i+cdw:i+cdw+dyf].plot(color = 'red',label='Days forward', ax=ax)
            ax.legend(labels=mylabels, loc=0)
            plt.tight_layout();
    return print(f'Average Return after {dyf} days is {round(np.mean(s)*100,2)}% \nfor {len(s)} occurrences\
    ----> {np.round(sum(1 for x in s if x>0)/len(s)*100,1)}% positive returns\n')



corr_window(data, 2, 0, -1)
```